# Duplicate Management Error in Process Builder?

Tags: process-builder, duplicate-management

I have a problem concerning the process builder. When the message "Duplicate Detected" is being displayed, and you press "Save, ignore warning", the users now get the error, that no flow could be triggered. Via E-Mail I get the following message:

UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- Error: (DUPLICATES_DETECTED)

How does that happen and how can I prevent it? Is it a bug or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem and it has been for the past four years: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000oMVgAAM

For myself, I am going to find out if I can replace the process with an old fashioned work flow. Update: this turned out not to be possible. The triggering record was a Task and the record that must be updated is an Account. Just the kind of thing that a process can do, but a work flow can't.

The solution for me was to do the update not immediately, but in the future. I moved the actions from direct to scheduled (well, moved: no, I copied them and then deleted the original). I used a one hour delay.

That way, the update is done way after the other update/creation has been done and there is no conflict. For me this works, because the concerning field does not need to be updated in real-time. A one hour delay is acceptable.

Comment: This answer is the correct one. based on the minimal info provide by the OP.
The question should have stated the setup of the Duplicate rule.
The only unknown info left to get from OP is: "Is the ProBuilder updating the dupe or firing from the Dupe???
The duplicate rule has alert checked and this is what is causing the bug within process builder. Alert is meant to only alert in the UI, but it is also for some reason causing an exception within Process builder.
THIS IS A BUG.
Salesforce need to fix it!
Ironically the when going to the idea page to upvote the idea  website was also buggy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of Order of Execution. Processes fire long AFTER Duplicate Rules are executed. You've not shared more details of your process, so that's the most definitive answer I can provide you with except to say that a Process cannot call a Duplicate Rule check to fire from with the process (BTW, a flow is different than a process). See [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) for more on the subject.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but shouldn't the duplicate rule fire and display the duplicate management error message, instead of the process firing an error?

Comment: If you "got" what I was saying, you'd understand that it's impossible for the duplicate rule to fire. It's also your responsibility to create error handlers in your processes to help diagnose these kinds of issues. You might want to keep in mind that not everyone has duplicate rules turned on in their orgs for all their objects.

Comment: Sorry, there was a miscommunication. I edited my original question. The message IS being displayed, the flow error comes when you then click "Save(Ignore warning)"

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. If the error message is being displayed, perhaps the issue is that you want to prevent your users from saving the duplicate? If so, you need to add logic to your flow should an error occur of that kind that automatically aborts the save and presents an error message of your own. See the documentation for how to present custom error messages and error handling in the Salesforce Help..

Comment: The problem is, that there is an error being displayed caused by the Duplicate Management. I want the user to be able to ignore the warning and save it. I know about duplicate rules, if I didn't want the record to be saved I would just not allow this from the beginning. The problem is, while the process is active, the duplicate management doesn't work like it should.

Comment: You may also want to look at [Why is the Record I'm trying to save being flagged as a Duplicate](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_rules_end_user_why_was_the_record_flagged_as_a_duplicate.htm&language=en_US). I'm not certain I can help further without more details. The person to ask would be Gupta in the Process Automation Group on the Success Community.

Comment: Yeah sorry I think we are not on the same level here. I know that a flow is different than a process, I am a Salesforce Dev myself, I know about the basics. This is not a matter of order of execution. The question is not, why the record I'm saving is being marked as a duplicate. The problem is that there is an error AFTER you ignore the warning. The error that occurs directly states "Duplicates detected" and I am not updating any fields in the process which are used in the duplicate management rules. So I guess it really just is a bug

Comment: I can see why this answer does not work, because the question does not have enough detail.
Yes this answer is not on point, sorry to say. the other answer is correct it is a bug.